# Which is correct, dozen other or dozen others?

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to write "dozen other" and "several other" in singular form as in the following quote from the CNN News of Nov. 29?

"Omicron was first identified by scientists in South Africa, who raised alarm over its unusually high number of mutations on Thursday. Since then, at least dozen other have confirmed cases of the new strain, with several other reporting suspected cases."

Answer (score 1):

"Dozen other" must have been a typo. I believe that is grammatically incorrect. "Several other" on the other hand, is grammatically correct.  Please correct me if my answers are wrong.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I also think that it is a typo. However I suspect that the original intention was to insert a plural noun after the word "other" but that the original was deleted and not replaced in the hurry to get the piece to publication. If the sentence was, for example, "Since then a dozen other _studies_ have confirmed..." it would be correct both grammatically and logically.

Comment: I'm sure @BoldBen's guess is correct. And I would argue, no, "with several other reporting..." is not valid. "Several" (in this use) takes a plural. If there were another noun ("several other countries"), then *other* would be an adjective. But without one, it's a pronoun, and as such is singular.

Comment: There's a lot of deletion going on here, it's almost headline-style. (It's not clear where the quote is from, if it was spoken, on screen, or on the website. It would be fine as an on-screen summary or subheading on the website, but isn't good English if intended as formal prose.)

Answer (score 0):

You are right; "dozen" and "several" do not normally modify singular nouns or pronouns (as BoldBen and Andy Bonner have pointed out in comments). The author probably meant:

> Since then, at least a dozen other scientists have confirmed cases of the new strain, with several other scientists reporting suspected cases.

Either or both instances of "other scientists" could be replaced by the pronoun "others", e.g.:

> Since then, at least a dozen others have confirmed cases of the new strain, with several others reporting suspected cases.

There is a bit of ambiguity about whether any of the second "others" are included in the first "others". If all of them are included, then you could drop the second "others" (and either consider it to be an elided element or consider "several" to be a pronoun):

> Since then, at least a dozen others have confirmed cases of the new strain, with several reporting suspected cases.